# Is it possible run an installing script to download and install all requirements of a ROS package?

Tags: python, cmake, ros, catkin

I have a ROS package that I want to distribute. It brings some dependencies that can't be installed via pip or package manager. They should be downloaded and installed manually. I wrote an installation script which is working fine, but I want all process to be autonomous in other words I want all dependencies installed with rosdep if possible.

Ideal implementation: 
- Create an external package which has the necessary CMakeLists file 
- Run the catkin_make to automatically download and install the libraries with my script (or run rosdep to install dependencies but I guess this is not possible)

Answer (score 0):

You should be able to use [wstool](http://wiki.ros.org/wstool) to set something up to accomplish this. [This tutorial](http://wiki.ros.org/catkin/Tutorials/workspace_overlaying) describes how to chain several catkin workspaces together. Your dependencies that need to be installed manually could be set up as their own catkin workspaces.